# how to show events in fullcalendar using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

hello please this is my first time using Fullcalendar, i add some events and there are stocked in the database but i can't display them in my calendar.

please can some one help me to fix that problem. i read the documentation of the full calendar but i did not understand how to use it:

my calendar code :

```
<?php
require_once('bdd.php');


$sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end,  FROM reservation_client ";

$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();

$events = $req->fetchAll();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' >


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 70px;
        /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
    }
    #calendar {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
    .col-centered{
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Free Calendar</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Menu</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>FullCalendar BS3 PHP MySQL</h1>
                <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
                <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">

              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ajouter un evenement</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> date debut</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">date fin</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
                    </div>
                  </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Clients</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <select class="form-control" name="id_client">
                        <option>Selectionnez un client </option>

                           <?php 
                            $req=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM customers' )/*or die (print_r($bdd->errorinfo()))*/;
                                while ($donnees = $req->fetch()) { 

                                echo'<option value='.$donnees['ID'].'>'.($donnees['NAME']) .'</option> '  ;                           
                                  }                   
                          ?>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


                  <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Chambre</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <select class="form-control" name="id_chambre">
                        <option>Selectionnez une chambre</option>

                           <?php 
                            $req=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM chambre' )/*or die (print_r($bdd->errorinfo()))*/;
                                while ($donnees = $req->fetch()) { 

                                echo"<option value='".$donnees['id']."'>".($donnees['libelle']) ."</option> "  ;                           
                                  }                   
                          ?>

                      </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">fermer</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">enregistrer</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Event</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                          <div class="checkbox">
                            <label class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox"  name="delete"> Delete event</label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- FullCalendar -->
    <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            select: function(start, end) {

                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD '));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },
            events: [
            <?php foreach($events as $event): 
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                },
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });

        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }

            id =  event.id;

            Event = [];
            Event[0] = id;
            Event[1] = start;
            Event[2] = end;

            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {Event:Event},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alert('Saved');
                    }else{
                        alert('Could not be saved. try again.'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });









</script>

</body>

</html>
```

my add events code:

```
<?php

// Connexion à la base de données
require_once('bdd.php');
//echo $_POST['title'];
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end']) ){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $end = $_POST['end'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO reservation_client(title, start, end) values ('$title', '$start', '$end')";
    //$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    //$req->execute();

    echo $sql;

    $query = $bdd->prepare( $sql );
    if ($query == false) {
     print_r($bdd->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur prepare');
    }
    $sth = $query->execute();
    if ($sth == false) {
     print_r($query->errorInfo());
     die ('Erreur execute');
    }

}
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the select query issue. Remove the comma after end column, otherwise you will get an error 'An expression was expected.'

```
SELECT id, title, start, end FROM reservation_client
```

convert the events data into JSON formatted string using json_encode and use.

like.

```
events: <?php print json_encode($events);?>,
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195415/discussion-on-answer-by-shivendra-singh-how-to-show-events-in-fullcalendar-using).